State transitions if condition is true on entry or becomes true later
I am developing a state machine model in MagicDraw. Very nearly all of my state transitions are doubled up, as this is how I was told to do it during the handover period.
ie, between two states I will have both [MyInteger >= 50] and when(MyInteger >=50)
The first operates if the condition is true on entry into the state, and the second if the condition becomes true while the state is already active.
This seems to be necessary because "when" only triggers on a false to true transition, and plain guards only appear to be evaluated on entry into the state.
Is there any way to combine these into a single arrow in the diagram? What I have works, but looks untidy.
I am talking specifically about the Cameo Simulation Toolkit in MagicDraw.

This is not completely correct. The first is called a completion transition. It fires, when the originating state completes its behavior. Behavior means here the substates and the entry and do behaviors. So, it is correct, when you want to leave the state on the completion event and on the change event you need two transitions. I for myself have not encountered such situations.
Maybe a state machine is not the right solution for your problem. I don't know what you are trying to achieve.
It is possible to have multiple triggers for one transition. However, not in combination with a completion transition, since UML recognizes such transitions by the absence of a trigger. It is possible to join the two transitions with a junction point and define the effect on the one outgoing transition segment. This way, you at least don't need to repeat it on both transitions.

Imagine the scenario where we have two states: Vehicle-Stationary and Vehicle-Moving. And we want to transfer from Stationary to Moving whenever VehicleSpeed > 5kph. Even if Vehicle speed > 5kph on entry to the Stationary state.
Surely that isn't all that unusual?

I find it strange that you want to enter the Stationary state when the speed is above 5 mph. Wouldn‘t it make more sense to go directly to Moving? Of course, maybe your Stationary is not the „stationary“ we know from everyday language. Is it necessary to use an uncommon definition?

Consider the behaviour when the system reinitialises with the vehicle moving.
Or, maybe consider the situation where condition 1 causes a transition from State A to state B, and condition 2 from B to C. And if condition 2 is set before condition 1, you still want to go A to B to C.

In this case I would go from Initializingto Moving. This might make it necessary to repeat some behavior, but the clarity of the model is more valuable than avoiding repetition. And in most cases repetition can be avoided with compound transitions with junction points.

If  the change event condition 2 triggers the transition from B to C, it should not implicitly trigger the transition from A to C. This is what state machines are about: Reaction to an event depends on the state. If that is not what you need, use an activity.

My point is that if the conditions are set in the order Condition1 then Condition2, I still want to end up in StateC, without requiring that Condition2 needs to cycle false-then-true while in StateB.

The behaviour I want is like you would get with the simplest possible C state machine code:
''''
Switch (state) {
case 1:
if (Condition1) state = 2;
break;
case 2:
if (Condiiton2) state = 3;
break;
case 3;
''''

The code you show is only about the behavior in one state. This state transitions to state 2 or state 3, depending on a condition. It doesn’t say, that you first go to state 2. It also omits to define at what time the condition is tested. Maybe you assume a loop. Then the loop will get broken by the condition becoming true. Of course, it will also get broken by the condition being true, but why are you entering a state you will immediately leave. Maybe you can save some repetition of transition effects, but I doubt that this is a good guideline for state modeling.

If you want to define that a condition becoming true is an event you eventually want to react to - just not in the current state - you can defer this event in this state. This way you always have a list of events a state will not simply ignore: Either it has a transition or a deferral.

I do not have any experience with this simulation toolkit, but I can tell you about how to interpret UML in general.
Summary: You may write the condition for a transition without brackets and without when. If that condition contains a variable x, you may assume that it is re-evaluated when the value of x changes and if the condition becomes true, the transition will be executed. One exception is described below.
I have seen many UML state machine diagrams, but I have never seen one with a transition in the form of when(...).
Example:

The initial state is State1. The condition x > 50 is immediately evaluated. If x > 50, the transition to State2 is executed. If not, the state machine remains 'waiting' in state State1. When the value of x changes after some time, such that the condition becomes true, then the transition to State2 is executed.
In general, a state machine diagram is just one piece of the greater design of an application. Another piece of the design may define how and when variable x is changed. For example, it may define use cases, where a user or an external system updates x. Normal practice is that you assume that the state machine somehow knows that it shall re-evaluate its transition conditions when one of the variables in these conditions changes and the state machine is 'waiting'.
It becomes tricky when the state machine itself is responsible for updating x, for example:

In this case, the initial state is again State1, but it first executes its entry behavior, incrementing x until it is 81, and then evaluates the transition condition. In this case, the transition is executed not when x becomes 50, but when it becomes 81. The reason is that the state machine is not 'waiting' while it executes its entry behavior.

I am talking specifically about the Cameo Simulation Toolkit in MagicDraw. And as far as I can tell this does require a "when(condition)" on the transition to force it to wait for a change. Though the behaviour observed is complicated by the existence of sub-state systems inside the main states.

I see. I have added one sentence to your question to make this clear. Unfortunately, I do not have any experience with this toolkit, so I cannot help you any further.

Sorry, but I respectfully disagree. A transition without trigger is implicitly triggered by the completion event. When this event occurs the guard is evaluated. If it is false, the event is removed from the pool and nothing happens. A completion event cannot happen multiple times in the same state, because of its very nature. By the way, I don’t see a problem, when the statemachine itself updates the value. The completion event occurs only after the behavior has completed. And an event could easily abort a do-behavior when it updates a value and this leads to a change event.

@AxelScheithauer, thank you, sorry, I made a mistake. My guards should have been triggers. I have now removed the square brackets from the conditions. You're also right about the do-behavior, but in my answer, I am talking about the entry behavior.  Do you have a reference to the UML spec that would make clear that a transition may occur when the entry behavior has not been completed?

The entry behavior runs to completion, but any change event happening in the meantime will be placed in the pool, where it will be retrieved once the entry behavior finishes. UML 2.5: „However, it is not defined specifically […] whether a ChangeEvent occurrence remains available for detection even if the associated changeExpression value changes back to false before the occurrence is consumed.“ So it could happen that it triggers the transition even when the condition is no longer given. To be on the save side a change event probably should be guarded by the same condition.
